# Can a browser plugin lazy load images?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, plugins

Before spending time learning the plug-in architecture I was hoping someone could let me know if what I want to do is even possible and possibly offer some guidance.

I've never written a browser plug-in before but I have am an experience programmer who is pretty good with JavaScript which I understand is what at least chrome extensions use. I have written a small app for the Samsung TV platform.

One webpage I visit on a regular basis loads a lot of images on a page and I don't want to wait until the developers improve the site. I'm hoping I could build a Chrome or Firefox extension that can identify when I'm viewing a page on that domain and prevent images from loading until some user interaction.

I was hoping when I changed the content settings in Chrome to not show images that there would be some way to individually load images (maybe a "show this image" in context menu, but there wasn't. Nothing came up when trying to search for an existing extension either.

Is it possible to have an extension manipulate the DOM to prevent the page from making requests for the images? I'm thinking replacing the src attribute with a local image as a placeholder, then changing it back depending on user interaction.

Comment: extensions and plugins are two different things. you need an extension or "add-on" to do the stuff you describe. that said, greasemonkey or tampermonkey can also do the job for a lot less effort.

Comment: Thank you @dandavis. I'm going to play around with tampermonkey. I found a script that does something similar to what I want for wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you again @dandavis this wound up being easier and better than I expected.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY I'm interested in what you ended up doing/if you would be willing to share your script if you wrote one up. Came up [over here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/force-image-lazy-loading-everywhere). I'm also interested in it for myself. thanks :) (comment here, there, in chat or via email (design@briarmoon.ca) - any of those would work great if you have a few minutes.

Comment: @NickWilde It was a real kludge made specifically for one site and they did things a little differently than other sites. I don't think the code will be of use to anyone else and it's a real mess. Basically tampermonkey allows you to inject your own javascript on webpages you visit so you just need to write code to lazy load. Might not work on all sites.